# Combine SQL View with Left Outer Join Query

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join, sql-view

I have a view called Home:

```
CREATE VIEW `skohr`.`Home` AS
Select Song_OID, Song_Name, Album_Name, Artist_First_Name, Artist_Last_Name, Band_Name, Genre, Album_Art_File_Path
From Song, Album, Artist, Track_Number, Made
Where Song_OID = Track_Number.Song_OID_FK AND Album_OID=Track_Number.Album_OID_FK AND Album_OID=Made.Album_OID_FK AND Artist_OID=Made.Artist_OID_FK
ORDER BY Song_Name Asc
```

I ran the following query on the view to get my desired table:

```
Select DISTINCT * From Home LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Song_Setting, user WHERE User_OID=User_OID_FK) AS UserSongs
ON Song_OID=Song_OID_FK
```

How do I combine the two separate queries into one to create a single view?

Comment: Have you tried adding a CREATE VIEW statement in front of the query?

Comment: Is this MySQL?  SQL Server?  Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

try just creating the View

```
CREATE VIEW `skohr`.`MyNewView` AS

Select DISTINCT * From Home h
LEFT OUTER JOIN Song_Setting x
    ON h.Song_OID_FK = x.Song_OID
INNER JOIN user u
    ON u.User_OID = x.User_OID_FK
```

Comment: I tried this before, but in doing so again, I got the following error message.
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1349: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `skohr`.`Home2` AS
Select DISTINCT * From Home 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT * FROM Song_Setting, user WHERE User_OID=User_OID_FK) AS UserSongs
     ON Song_OID=Song_OID_FK

Answer (score -1):

::Response to comment requesting MySQL version::

I don't specifically use MySQL today, but is there any reason you could not use a subquery as you have for your other data set?  Something like this:

```
Select DISTINCT * From 
(
    Select Song_OID, Song_Name, Album_Name, Artist_First_Name, Artist_Last_Name, Band_Name, Genre, Album_Art_File_Path
    From Song, Album, Artist, Track_Number, Made
    Where Song_OID = Track_Number.Song_OID_FK AND Album_OID=Track_Number.Album_OID_FK AND Album_OID=Made.Album_OID_FK AND Artist_OID=Made.Artist_OID_FK
) as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Song_Setting, user WHERE User_OID=User_OID_FK) AS b
ON a.Song_OID=b.Song_OID_FK
```

And if that will not work for MySQL, I think you may be left with looking into using temporary / in-memory tables.  So look into creating temp tables in MySQL, create a temp table and fill it with the sub-query I captured in a CTE below, then join that into your other query.

If this is SQL Server, you can utilize [CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Just drop the following code into a View and it should give you what you want.

```
WITH Home AS 
(
Select Song_OID, Song_Name, Album_Name, Artist_First_Name, Artist_Last_Name, Band_Name, Genre, Album_Art_File_Path
From Song, Album, Artist, Track_Number, Made
Where Song_OID = Track_Number.Song_OID_FK AND Album_OID=Track_Number.Album_OID_FK AND Album_OID=Made.Album_OID_FK AND Artist_OID=Made.Artist_OID_FK
)
Select DISTINCT * From Home 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Song_Setting, user WHERE User_OID=User_OID_FK) AS UserSongs
ON Song_OID=Song_OID_FK
```

Comment: For clarification, I am working with MySQL. Do you have an alternative method that would work with MySQL?

Comment: Edited with further thoughts now that I know it's MySQL specific.